# Spring Data JPA Entity result set mapping for Composite Primary Key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to map a stored procedure result set to Entity using Entity resultset mapping. I am using composite primary key to define the keys for the stored procedure result set. I am having trouble mapping the embedded Id (primary key) to entity result set mapping. It's failing with undefined column found in the result set. I am sure there should be a work around for this. Please let me know what I am missing.

**Here is my entity and composite key class definitions:**

```
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@SqlResultSetMapping(
  name = "CreditCardMapping",
  entities = {
    @EntityResult(
      entityClass = AccountCreditCard.class,
      fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "customerNumber", column = "OCUSTNO"),
        @FieldResult(name = "creditCardNumber", column = "OCCMASK"),
        @FieldResult(name = "expirationDate", column = "OCCEXPDATE")

      }
    )
  }
)
@Entity
public class AccountCreditCard implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @EmbeddedId private CreditCardKey creditCardKey;
  private String customerNumber;
  private String creditCardNumber;
  private String expirationDate;


// Constructors and Getters/setters



import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class CreditCardKey implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String creditCardNumber;

  private String expirationDate;

//Constructors and Getters/setters
```

**Error Message:**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve column name in result set [creditCardKey]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.resolveColumnPosition(JdbcResultMetadata.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:482)
```

I tried the alternate way of implementing Composite key as well using Idclass.

**Approach 2:**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@SqlResultSetMapping(
  name = "CreditCardMapping",
  entities = {
    @EntityResult(
      entityClass = AccountCreditCard.class,
      fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "customerNumber", column = "OCUSTNO"),
        @FieldResult(name = "creditCardNumber", column = "OCCMASK"),
        @FieldResult(name = "expirationDate", column = "OCCEXPDATE")

      }
    )
  }
)
@Entity
@IdClass(CreditCardKey.class)
public class AccountCreditCard implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  private String customerNumber;
  @Id
  private String creditCardNumber;
  @Id
  private String expirationDate;


// Constructors and Getters/setters
```

**Repository Impl:**

```
public interface CreditCardRepository
    extends JpaRepository<AccountCreditCard, CreditCardKey>,
        AccountCreditCardRepositoryCustom {}
```

**I still see the same error:**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An undefined column name was detected.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:389)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:366)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDServerRow.findField(JDServerRow.java:390)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.findColumn(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:514)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getString(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3253)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getString(WSJdbcResultSet.java:1878)
```

Comment: Following your first approach, try like this - @FieldResult(name = "creditCardKey.customerNumber", column = "OCUSTNO"),

Comment: @SB This did not work. Can you explain why you suggested to include key name with customer number?

Comment: Typically that is the convention when using composite keys as embeddable. Since the error is on undefined column name detected, suspecting the column names and their entity mappings are not matching.